# Mute button won't toggle / un-mute

Tags: button, mute, media-buttons

On my old DELL Latitude D620 I'm running Lubuntu. The mute button won't toggle / un-mute. I press it and it mutes fine. But when i press it again it won't un-mute. I have to use the mouse an go to the volume control setting and un-check the mute box.
Any suggestion on how to fix this nuisance? -Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem on my Dell D630; it's a Lubuntu thing.

- Open Menu>Prefrences>Setup Hot Keys
- Click the 'Programs' tab and locate the command "amixer -q sset Master toggle"
- Double-click the command and modify to this: "amixer -D pulse -q sset Master toggle".

This will make the mute button toggle properly. If you want the volume keys to unmute as well, the command "-D pulse" can be inserted into those commands in the same fashion (e.g.: "amixer -D pulse -q sset Master 3%+ unmute")

Hope this helps!